# Efficient SQL query for selecting records where a related record DOES NOT exist

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server

I am trying to select a User where that User DOES NOT have an associated record with a certain value.

I have a User model, a User has_one Feed, a Feed has_many FeedTracks, a FeedTrack belongs_to a Track. I want to select Users only where they DO NOT have a FeedTrack with a certain TrackId.

I'm using rails but I would be open to strict SQL for this.

The best I've got is:

```
 SELECT TOP 1000 * 
 FROM Users u
 LEFT JOIN Feeds f ON f.user_id = u.id
 LEFT JOIN FeedTracks ft ON ft.feed_id = f.id
 ONLY IF ALL OF THOSE feedTracks' track_id !== <<track_id>>
```

Obviously that last part statement is not real SQL and that's what my question is. How would I say, hey, get me the Users where this related record doesn't exist. But if that record does exist, don't return that User.

In other words, if that user has a feed, with a feed track with that track id, don't return that User. But if it doesn't, do return that User.

Comment: it seems like you define wrong schema, if user has one feed, feeds table should have `user_id` column, instead of users table has `feed_id` column. Please post your schema of database.

Comment: good catch, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUP  BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT u.id
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN Feeds f 
    ON f.id = u.feed_id
LEFT JOIN FeedTracks ft 
    ON ft.feed_id = f.id
GROUP BY u.id
HAVING 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ft.track_id = @track_id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

*Modify the columns in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` as needed.*

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
User.joins(feed: :feed_tracks)
        .where('feed_tracks.track_id <> ?', unwanted_track_id)
        .order('id desc')
        .limit(1000)
        .to_sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `not existst` operation  like this

```
 SELECT TOP 1000 * 
 FROM Users u
    LEFT JOIN Feeds f ON f.id = u.feed_id
    LEFT JOIN FeedTracks ft ON ft.feed_id = f.id
 where not exists 
(select 1 
from FeedTracks  ft1 
where ft1.feed_id = f.id 
  and ft1.track_id = <<track_id>>)
```